# C++ Class property not recognised by other class (headers incl., public)

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have two classes each in Header files called "Map" and "Character". "Map" has a class called "map" and "Character" has a class called "character". 
Class "map" inherits class "character", and both have the header file of the other included.
In one of the methods of class "map", I use a property member from class "character", and that works fine. However, when I try to use a "map" property member in class "character" it does not work. This happens regardless of whether or not "map" inherits "character".

This is class map which works fine:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Character.h"
#include "AI.h"

using namespace std;

class map: public character
{
public:
static const int mapRow = 30; //-- all maps are the same size
static const int mapColumn = 116;
char marr[mapRow][mapColumn];

map()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<mapRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<mapColumn; j++)
        {
                marr[i][j] = ' ';//set whole array to blank
        }
    }
}

void display(void);
void level1(void);
void level2(void);
void level3(void);
void treeBlueprint(int);
};
//displays the map

void map::display(void)
{
    //This displays the level
    for (int i = 0; i<mapRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<mapColumn; j++)
        {
        cout << marr[i][j];
        }
    cout << "\n";
     }
}
```

This is class character that gives me the following errors when compiled:

- 'map':is not a class or namespace name
- 'map':is not a class or namespace name
- 'mapColumn': undeclared identifier
- 'mapRow': undeclared identifier

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include "Map.h"
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  class character
    {
      int hpPool = 100;
      int currentHp =hpPool;

   public:
       char Tommy ='?';
  int position1;
  int position2;
  char movement;

   character()
  {
      position1 = 5;
      position2 = 5;
     movement = '0';
   }

  void moveUp(void);
  void moveDown(void);
  void moveLeft(void);
  void moveRight(void);
  void moveFunct(void);
   };

        void character::moveUp(void)
       {
         if (position1 != 1)
        {
          position1--;
         }
          else
         {
         //Hitting a wall
        }
     }

      void character::moveDown(void)
      {
        if (position1 != (map::mapRow-2))
      {
        position1++;
      }
     else
     {
      //Hitting a wall
     }
  }

     void character::moveLeft(void)
  {
     if (position2 != 1)
      {
      position2--;
      }
       else
       {
        //Hitting a wall
       }
  }

      void character::moveRight(void)
     {
     if (position2 != (map::mapColumn-2))
     {
      position2++;
      }
     else
     {
          //Hitting a wall
      }
    }

  void character::moveFunct(void)
   {
      switch (movement)
      {
      case 'w': moveUp();
          break;
    case 'a': moveLeft();
        break;
     case 's': moveDown();
        break;
     case 'd': moveRight();
      break;
      }
    }
  ```

Comment: `using namespace std;` followed by `class map: public character` is just a bad idea.

Comment: I seem to still have the error when I take it out

Comment: FYI, remove void keyword on parameters on function signatures, it's unnecessary in C++

Comment: I know, but I like the habit because it lets me know that I didn't forget to type anything, just a personal thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.h` is including `Character.h` and vice-versa, but that doesn't work (it would create infinite inclusion recursion if it weren't for the `#pragma once`).

Since `character` can not depend on `map` (because `map` is a derived class from `character`), it should not include `Map.h`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions to improve your code base:

1. Remove `using namespace std;`.
2. `map` is already a class in the `std` namespace. It will be better to use a different name or use it under a namespace of your own.

---

```
namespace MyApp
{
   class character { ... };
}

namespace MyApp
{
   class map : public character { ... };
}
```